# Open a separate browser from an app(ios/android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs

I am building a web page using angularjs/pure javascript.

This web page will be used inside an app both in iOS and Android. I am trying to open a separate webpage in a separate browser, but every time it opens in the app view itself.

Below are the methods I tried, unfortunately it does not work.

```
window.open(url, '_blank');

window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Kindly provide some inputs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iOS :-

```
  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Hi Nancy, this is native code. I need to trigger it from my js file.

Comment: window.open(url, "_self") try this

Comment: _self will open in the current frame. I need to open outside the app in a separate browser.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp  check this if it could be of any help.

Comment: Thanks Nancy. Unfortunately it works only for a browser. Inside app, it still opens in the current webview. I am looking for something that will open then default browser of the device.